# SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW automatically granted via updating from Google Play?

Tags: android

I have read on stackoverflow that

> Every app that requests the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission and that is
>   installed through the Play Store (version 6.0.5 or higher is
>   required), will have the permission granted automatically for the app.

But what about situation when we add this permission in existed app and updated it from Google Play?

I have tried to test it and this permission in my app was not granted when I update it, only when I install a new one.

Comment: Doesn't the Play Store tell you "this app has introduced some new permission, press ok to accept and install updated'? If I'm not mistaken there should be such a dialog prompting.

Comment: But according to (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen.

Comment: Manual application updates are followed by  'Run Time permission popup' for the user. Refer: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/app-permissions-work-care-android/

Comment: @ManmeetP it was written 4 years ago. Have you ever heard about normal, dangerous and special permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every app that requests the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission and that is
>   **installed** through the Play Store (version 6.0.5 or higher is
>   required), will have the permission granted automatically for the app.

See that "**installed**" word there? It is not about update, but about clean install. You cannot automatically handle permissions (even through update) on user's device after s/he has it installed. That could lead to security flaws in theory.

Comment: But why on some devices after updating this permission is automatically approved?

Comment: Please provide more specific information on your steps and observations.